# Mysql replication error: option '--rpl-user' is required

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up replication from a local database to a remote one. I'm new to MySQL so i followed the video on there website. Created the users, granted the permissions the entered in on the master:

```
mysqlreplicate --master=repl@localhost:3306 --slave=repl@myDomain.com:3306
```

It gives me this error:

```
error: option '--rpl-user' is required
```

Answer (score 0):

Per  [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqlreplicate.html) , looks like that's a required command line options.

> --rpl-user=
>
> ```
> The user and password for the replication user, 
>   in the format: <user>[:<password>] or <login-path>. The default is rpl:rpl.
> ```

Your command should look like below where `rpl:rpl` is the default for `--rpl-user` command line option.

```
mysqlreplicate --master=repl@localhost:3306 --slave=repl@myDomain.com:3306 --rpl-user=rpl:rpl
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that but it gives me this error: `File "scripts\mysqlreplicate.py", line 161, in <module>
  File ".\mysql\utilities\common\server.py", line 520, in check_hostname_alias
  File ".\mysql\utilities\common\server.py", line 921, in is_alias
  File ".\mysql\utilities\common\server.py", line 774, in _update_alias
ValueError: too many values to unpack`